# Why hybris jalo layer generate two classes for an item

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

For an item type `MyType`, hybris generate two classes.

```
a. Gensrc/de/hybris/jalolayer/sample/GeneratedMyType.java
b. src/de/hybris/jalolayer/sample/MyType.java
```

As I went through the documentation,

`GeneratedMyType.java` is an abstract class that contains getter and setter methods, whereas `MyType.java` is the subclass that extends the abstract class `GeneratedMyType.java`.

`MyType.java` extends `GeneratedMyType` and provide business logic.

As I see one advantage, whenever item type is changed in items.xml, hybris can override `GeneratedMyType.java`. In this way, hybris can reflect new properties attached to the item type in items.xml. Is there any other advantages of generating abstract and concrete classes for the same item type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage you mentioned is the most important advantage, as any business logic you implement in MyType.java does not get overridden by the generation process. The generation process only generates/modifies GeneratedMyType.java.